# Minimum value of $f(x) = \sqrt{x^2 + (1-x)^2} + \sqrt{(1-x)^2 +(1+x)^2}$

Tags: contest-math

If  $f(x) = \sqrt{x^2 + (1-x)^2} + \sqrt{(1-x)^2 +(1+x)^2}$

Find the minimum value of the function

I tried using the AMGM inequality and differentiation but didn't know how to solve it any ideas?

This is from a math competition. ( I would like to see the most efficient way as I think differentiation in a math competition is not that efficient)

Using Mogjals comment and using the AM-GM inequality , setting $A = \sqrt{x^2 + (1-x)^2}$ and $B=\sqrt{(1-x)^2 +(1+x)^2}$

then

$A+B \geq 2\sqrt{AB}$

$$  \sqrt{x^2 + (1-x)^2} + \sqrt{(1-x)^2 +(1+x)^2} \geq 2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{x^2+1}\sqrt{2x^2-2x+1}$$

With equality if and only $A=B$ so $x=-\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: df(x)/dx=0 when y is minimum

Comment: Sorry, but $x=-\frac12$ is not the correct answer.

In fact, you first derived an inequality that says $f(x)\geq g(x)$, then you found $x^*$ such that $f(x^*)=g(x^*)$, and finally concluded $f(x^*)$ is the minimum of $f(x)$. Generally, this is not always a correct approach. For example, consider $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=2x-1$. Starting from $(x-1)^2\geq0$, you can easily verify $f(x)\geq g(x)$. In this example, $f(x^*)=g(x^*)$ leads to ${x^*}^2=2x^*-1$, and then  $x^*=1$. But obviously you can say $f(1)$ is the minimum of $f(x)$, because $f(0)=0$ is the true minimum.

Comment: But, if you find a constant function for $g(x)$ (i.e., $g(x)=k$), then you can say the minimum of $f(x)$ is $f(x^*)$, if such $x^*$ exists. In the aforementioned example, $g(x)=0$ is the constant function we need. So the correct answer of the problem is that explained by *juantheron*.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Let $A=(0,1)$, $B=(1,1)$, and $C=(-x,x)$ as in the picture. Then 
$$AC=\sqrt{x^2+(1-x)^2}, BC=\sqrt{(1+x)^2+(1-x)^2}.$$
Let $D$ be symmetric to $A$ about $x+y=0$ (trajectory of $C$). Apparently
$$AC+BC\ge BD=AE+BE.$$
Minimal is attained at $C=E$. I leave you figure the coordinates of $E$.

Comment: Very good geometrical demonstration.

Comment: Just one question, how did you make the nice animation?

Comment: @Babak: [Geogebra](https://www.geogebra.org/) to the rescue.

Answer (score 2):

Using **Minkowski Inequality**

$$\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+\sqrt{c^2+d^2}\geq \sqrt{(a+c)^2+(b+d)^2}$$

and equality hold when $\displaystyle \frac{a}{b} = \frac{c}{d}$

So $$\sqrt{x^2+(1-x)^2}+\sqrt{(1-x)^2+(1+x)^2}\geq \sqrt{[x+(1-x)]^2+[(1-x)+(1+x)]^2}=\sqrt{5}$$

and Equality hold when $$\frac{x}{1-x}=\frac{1-x}{1+x}\Rightarrow x^2-2x+1=x^2+x\Rightarrow x=\frac{1}{3}$$

Comment: Excellent *juantheron*.

Answer (score 1):

A posible way: Let $A,B,C$ a triangle and $AD$ the height. The problem is $AD=1-x$, $BD=x$, $CD=1+x$ and you want minimize $BA+AC$, but note that the area is fixed ($(1-x)(2x+1)/2$), then this sum is minime if the triangle is right in A.

Answer (score 1):

Write $f(x)=g(x)+h(x)$. Now $g(x)$ has minima at $x=1/2$ and $h(x)$ is increasing function with minima at $x=0$.Then $f(x)$ has minima at ?

Comment: Does f(x) have a minima at x=1/2?

Comment: You question does not make sense: $f_\varepsilon(x) = g(x)+\varepsilon h(x)$ has minima at?